# Cordova Inappbrowser not showing alerts on iOS

Tags: cordova, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap-build, inappbrowser

I'm having a little issue that is starting to give me a headache.

While using phone gap build, I'm sending my phone a notification through Firebase Cloud Messaging. Everything works great, except when the app is in use, or in the foreground, the inappbrowser is causing the notification to not show. Notification is received, but it is covered up by the inappbrowser. This only occurs in iOS.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
window.push.on('notification', function(data){
navigator.notification.window.alert(
    data.message,
    null,
    data.title,
    'Ok'
);
});
```

Comment: is it possible to see the inapp code? And also which Plug-in you have used.